# Setting a boolean if equals true/false in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, vba, boolean

In VBA I have used similar code to below to set a boolean value, is there a way to accomplish somthing similar in .NET using shorthand?

```
Dim A As Boolean
Dim B As Integer
Dim C As Integer

A = B = C
```

Set A to true or false if B equals C

The full statement would be:

```
If B = C Then
  A = True
Else
  A = False
End If
```

Comment: using c# you can write a = b == c;

Comment: in C#: `A = B == C;` - there's a *reason* it has different operators for assignment and equality

Comment: Trying it out yourself would have given you the answer faster than the time it took you to write up this question.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I did try it myself. It didnt work hence why I asked to check the correct syntax. My code is obviously incorrect.

Comment: @Obsidian: did you though? I don't know VB.NET and I just copied your code. https://dotnetfiddle.net/huel6J

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Yes! that's why I said. "I did try it myself". The test was in my existing code though. Additionally your fiddle states true/false as Integers?

Comment: Yeah, I missed that part of the question. Although VB.NET doesn't seem to care and compiles it happily; changing it to `1` and `2` works as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can just write (in VB.NET) `A = B = C`

That works in the way you expect. I would suggest that you add some brackets to improve readability:

```
A = (B = C)
```

Also make sure you have `Option Strict On` to avoid type conversion errors that are difficult to spot.

In C# you would have to write:

```
A = (B == C);
```

Comment: since when in NET you can do `B = C` on `int`s and not `B == C`?

Comment: @vba4all ".NET" is not a language; the question and this answer is in VB. You're thinking of C#

Comment: @MarcGravell obviously .NET is not a language but the question is tagged C#. The `Dim` statement used in VBA and the OP didn't specify if he is using C# or VB.NET

Comment: @vba4all it is also tagged asp.net, vb.net, vba and boolean; your point is...? It is very obvious from the question that the syntax is VB.

Comment: Is it? the OP said in `VBA` and presented the `Dim A as Boolean` which is the correct **VBA syntax**. He never said he is looking for a VB.NET solution. Just a .NET solution - so your assumption that he was looking for a VB.NET code is not 100% backed up, is it? and that's my point.

Comment: @vba4all - the point is that there is no one solution that will satisfy all .Net languages. That is why I have provided an answer to both VB.NET and C# (the two tagged in the question)